# Vector not in span$\left(S\right)$ implies $S\cup\{\vec{X}\}$ be linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Theorem:
>   Let S be a linearly independent set in a vector space. If $\vec{X} \in V$ and $\vec{X} \in span \left(S\right)$ then $S \cup \{\vec{X}\}$ is linearly independent.

Proof:

It suffices to show, by contra positivity, that $\vec{X}$ $\in$ $span\left(S\right)$.

Let $S = \{\vec{v}_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$

$\vec{0} = c_{X}\vec{X} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\vec{v}_{i}$ with coefficients $c_{i} = c_{X} = 0, \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}_{1}^{n}$.

Rearranging:

$\vec{X} = \frac{1}{c_{X}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\vec{v}_{i}$

Here, I am unable to move forward. The reciprocal of $c_{X}$ gives an undefined value.

Any help to move this proof forward is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You stated the theorem incorrectly: It is supposed to have $\vec{X} \notin Span(S)$, instead of $\vec{X} \in Span(S)$.  The theorem as-stated is false (for example take $\vec{X}=\vec{0} \in Span(S)$).

Comment: Your sentence $\vec{0} = c_X\vec{X} + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \vec{v}_i$ "with coefficients $c_i=c_X=0$ for all $i$" does not make sense (particularly the part in quotes) since if you define those coefficients to be zero you get $\vec{0}=\vec{0}$ and the equation is useless to work with.  That is not the definition of linear independence...you need to show that if the equation holds, _then all coefficients must be zero_ (you are not supposed to _assume_ they are zero, you must _prove_ they are zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $\vec{x} \notin \operatorname{span}(S)$, as the assumtion of course (as you do have in the title).

In that case we can show that $S \cup \{\vec{x}\}$ is lin. independent:

Suppose no, then there are vectors $\vec{s_1},\dots \vec{s_n} \in S$ and coefficients $c_1,\ldots c_n, c$, not all $0$, such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \vec{s_i} + c\vec{x} = 0$$

If $c =0$ we have an immediate contradiction with the fact that $S$ is linearly independent, because not all the $c_i$ are $0$.

So we must have $c \neq 0$ and so $\frac{1}{c}$ is a well-defined scalar.

But then $$\vec{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{c}(-c_i) s_i$$ and we'd have that $\vec{x} \in \operatorname{span}(S)$ contrary to the (corrected) assumption.

Comment: I made a mistake in the theorem. The vector X is not supposed to be in the span of the set S.

Comment: @Mathematicing I worked from the assumption that $\vec{x}$ indeed is not in the span of $S$.